# Excel: Enter the date from a cell if the word "fail" is in a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a date from A5:A999 to appear in L3 if the word Fail appears in column K5:k999.

Column A will have a different date in each cell of the column.  Column K will either have nothing or the word "Fail" in each cell of the Column.  L3 is the target cell I want the date from A5 to appear if the word fail appears in the cell K.  There will be five rows like this in a set and each set of five will repeat with a different date in column A and possible  blank or fail in column k

```
A5          B5         C5        D5   E5   F5    G5    H5   I5  J5    K5              L3
9/5/2020  master    near gate    no   no   8.7   0.0   0.0            Fail           9/5/2020
```

[image: IMG:]

## Sample Data

```
8/20/2020 | Master     |
7/31/2020 | Camera     |
8/10/2020 | Regular 1  |
8/10/2020 | Regular 2  |
8/20/2020 | Flash      |
8/08/2020 | Master     |
8/08/2020 | Camera     |
8/20/2020 | Regular 1  |
8/20/2020 | Regular 2  |
8/20/2020 | Flash Only |
```

Comment: Can you possibly show a larger snapshot? E.g. Set A5:A10 are dates in A5:A10 same or different? Does word Fail if appears so, anywhere in K5:K10 within a set of 5? Does L in a set supposed to show only one date or all, if one should it be the first row in that set?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a lookup - assuming there's only one 'Fail' in the whole sheet? What if there are more than one fail, where do the other dates go if J3 is already taken?

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A5:$A$999,MATCH("Fail",$K$5:$K$999,0)),"")` will give you the date for the first time 'Fail' appears. For a more complete answer, [edit] your question to add the information requested.

Comment: No, there could be multiple "fail" in the sheet.  Every 5th row is the same unit being measured.  So, if unit one fails at any one of the hundreds of readings I want the date of the fail to be printed in another cell.  I want the date for this unit in L3.  2nd unit 's info is in A6, third is in A7, so on and so on. if K6 is fail the date of faileur would go into L4, so on and so on.

Comment: The date for the first fail is  7/31/2020

Comment: snap shot in link above,  This web site said Im not able to post an image yet.

Comment: Thank you for any help!

Comment: dare I ask why the date of failure gets shifted up 2 rows?  Is column L just a list of failure dates that don't line up with the failure flag in column F? Can you give a mock up with a smaller data set with expected results?  IE  columns B to J apparently have no bearing on the date

Comment: Failure date will be shifted up over a hundred rows, and data will be entered in the sheet for hundreds more.  The snap shot is from the 150th row and I am up to almost 300 now with 1-3 data points a day.  The colors organize and sort the particular unit.                                 Simply put, If the word fail is entered into one cell, I want the date of that failure, Located in the same row but different column, to appear in a third cell far up the sheet.

Comment: The colors of the rows correspond the unit to the fail.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to adjust the references to suit your needs.

The following formula will pull the date from any row that has the word "Fail" in the same row.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$6:$C$34)/($C$6:$C$34="FAIL"),ROW(A1))),"")
```

The above formula is place in E6 of the example and copied down.  The aggregate function performs array like operation without being an array formula.  As a result, avoid using full column references within the aggregate function.  Drag the formula down as needed.  Excessive use or large ranges within the formula may result in slow performance.

[image]

If you only need the date from the yellow rows, I would suggest adding a helper column that will flag the yellow row as failed if something in the previous 4 rows is failed.  Reference that helper column when checking for failure flags.

Comment: Forward Ed,  Thank you for your guidance, but could you dumb it down for me?

Comment: Forward Ed,  Thank you for your guidance, but could you dumb it down for me?  Row A4,A9,A14,A20 so on so on for hundreds of rows are all the same unit.  If fail is in column K  I want the date from that row to appear in column cell L20.  Row A5,A10,A15, A21 are a different unit and I want the date from a put into L21 if fail is in k.  It will be this way for 5 different units.  I know I don't fully understand your answer, and plugging it into my sheet did not work.  I would not even begin to know how a helper column works. Thank you for any further assistance.

Comment: Please mock up a small sample set of data with expected results.  Sounds like you need 3 columns: date, unit name, fail status.  And an expected results.  Edit your original post to include this info.

Comment: Been reading comments and find the wording confusing.  when you refer to UNITS that can be unit A,  B, or C or any combination of unit names.  hard to understand if at times you are talking about a unique unit such as just unit A or talking about all units.  Hence why I asked for the data mock up earlier.  I also currently do not understand what roll the group of 5 units (A,B,C,D,E)  has to play in getting the list of failure dates.  The solution above is just a list of all failure dates.  It does not care about which unit (A, B, C or D)  the date belonged to.

Comment: Are you trying to get a sequential list of failure dates grouped by unit name?  ie list all the unit A failures, then list all the unit B failures etc?

Comment: It sounded like a single unit can fail in multiple rows.  if only a single date is being recorded, which date do you want record, earliest row, latest row, earliest date, latest date?

Comment: Yes sequential list of failure dates.  Each unit is a separate signal trailer. There are 5 trailers each unique, each failing at different times.  All dates to be listed under each particular trailer's name:  Master, Camera, Regular 1 Regular 2, Flash.                                                                 
Master Camera Regular #1 Regular #2 Flash Only
8/20/2020 7/31/2020 8/10/2020 8/10/2020 8/20/2020
 8/8/2020 8/8/2020 8/20/2020 
 8/20/2020 8/20/2020

Comment: Master :   8/20/2020      Camera: 7/31/2020, 8/8/2020,8/20/2020 Regular #1: 
  Regular #2 :8/10/2020,8/20/2020    Flash Only: 8/20/2020

Comment: I can't seem to post a screen shot of the mock up, sorry

Comment: don't do it as a screen shot, just type it in as text so it can be copied and pasted into peoples spreadsheets for use.

Comment: _"Each unit is a separate signal trailer"_ what does that mean?